# Does NServiceBus support availability zone or geo-replication for Azure ServiceBus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, nservicebus, servicebus, disaster-recovery

According to the Microsoft docs it is possible to run Azure SB in a mode that makes it fail safe in a disaster via geo- or availability-zone replication. Does NSB support this mode? And if yes, is it transparent to the user of NSB, meaning easier to handle or configure?
The idea is that that the service bus should always be available, in an "outage" and in a "disaster" case where Azure SB is partially or fully unavailable.

Answer (score 4):

Geographical disaster recovery (Geo-DR) and high availability (HA) are broker-side [features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters) and do not rely on the client. Both features are supported by Azure Service Bus **Premium** and do not require anything from NServiceBus users.

HA is achieved by enabling [Azure Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview) when a namespace is provisioned.
Geo-DR is supported by the broker but requires a fail-over namespace to be provisioned.

A few important notes:

1. The fail-over namespace needs to be a Premium namespace as well.
2. The failed namespace cannot be re-used due to the fail-forward nature of the feature and will require another namespace to be provisioned.
3. The fail-over can be triggered manually or automatically.
4. Additional [documented consideration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr#considerations) when planning your Geo-DR.

A good starting point for Geo-DR would be this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr).

When it comes to executing, the Az CLI [`az servicebus georecovery-alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/georecovery-alias?view=azure-cli-latest) command to manage Service Bus Geo-DR can be very helpful.